# github and maven for java collaboration

Tags: maven, version-control, github

New maven and relatively new to java...

I would like to collaborate on a project in java with fellow classmates. I would like to manage the build with maven and software configuration with github. After reading a bit about it I have the following impression:

Using the two together is simply a matter of pointing a github repository at my local maven project folder. All builds and dependencies will be handled locally with source changes being committed per the strictures of github. The situation becomes more complicated if I wish for github to do something other than configuration, such as hosting the project as a maven repository.

Is my understanding of the situation correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "hosting the project as a maven repository"?

Comment: @JBNizet Not sure. That seems to be what most questions on stackoverflow and elsewhere are addressing. I took it to mean using github to release your project to be used as a dependency elsewhere. I do not need to do that. I just need version control for people working on the same java project.

Comment: It looks like you got it right. Maven is used to build a project. Github is used to host and manage the sources of a project. They have nothing in common.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. Searching for maven and github together yielded secondary use cases that confused the hell out of me. If you post a similar answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are best advised to only use github for managing source code. Consider installing a dedicated repository manager like one of the following for sharing binaries:

- [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)
- [Aritfactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi)

A repository manager is also useful for caching artifacts downloaded from 3rd party repositories like [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/). I find it an essential component of my ALM infrastructure.

### Update

There was a recent Sonatype blog posting called "[Wait... You don't have a repository manager?](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2012/07/wait-you-dont-have-a-repository-manager/)" which gives some explanation as to why people won't use a repository manager.

Comment: Thanks. With respect to caching 3rd party artifacts, what does a repository manager do (or do better) that maven does not?

Comment: I've seen plenty of cases where one developer's local repository becomes out of sync with anothers. The only way to ensure build repeatability is periodically purge your local repo. Treat it like a cache.